# Why is a monospace font set to 80em taking up less than 80 columns of text?

Tags: css, fonts, monospace

I'm trying to make some text on a webpage look like a page from Gopherspace.  In other words, monospace font with a maximum of 80 columns.  I figured that if the font is monospace and I set the width of the containing element to `80em`, that would constrain it to a perfect 80 columns since every character should be the same width in a monospace font.

The colors I've added are just to make it easier to tell where line breaks occur.

In case this works on some browsers/computers and not others, here's what I see on my computer, which is running Firefox 65.0.1 on Mac OS 10.14.3.

[image: longer than 80 columns]

Why is this div almost twice the size of 80 columns of text and how can I fix it?

```css
.plaintext {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 80em;
  font-size: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.r { color: red; }
.o { color: orange; }
.y { color: yellow; }
.g { color: green; }
.b { color: blue; }
.i { color: indigo; }
.v { color: violet; }
```

```html
<div class="plaintext">
  <span class="r">0123456789</span><span class="o">0123456789</span><span class="y">0123456789</span><span class="g">0123456789</span><span class="b">0123456789</span><span class="i">0123456789</span><span class="v">0123456789</span><span class="r">0123456789</span>
</div>
```

Comment: When I tried changing it to 80ch, it was only as wide as 40 characters. ???

Comment: That's strange, I changed it and it worked as desired. I may be confused about what the desired outcome is though.

Comment: @MrLister so you confirm you have all the characters in one line? I am also getting 2 lines when using 1ch

Comment: @MrLister nevermind, I got confused with his list, each color contain 20 charaters not 10

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, the OP's text contains 160 characters. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/gbuanyp0/)'s a fiddle, just in case.

Comment: Oops.  That's my mistake.  I'll update it.  In that case, `ch` is the right way to go.  Sorry about that.  @MrLister, would you like to make an official answer to get credit for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font size of a element (measured in `em`) is the height of the font, not the width.
(Originally, the word "em" refers to the width of the M, but not many fonts have an M exactly the width of 1em any more.)

The solution is to use `ch` as a unit for the width. In monospace fonts, `1ch` is the width of a character. In variable-width fonts, `1ch` is the width of the 0 (zero) character.
See the [official definition at the W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#lengths) or the more readable [MDN version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length).

```css
.plaintext {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 80ch;      /* changed */
  font-size: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.r { color: red; }
.o { color: orange; }
.y { color: yellow; }
.g { color: green; }
.b { color: blue; }
.i { color: indigo; }
.v { color: violet; }
```

```html
<div class="plaintext">
  <span class="r">0123456789</span><span class="o">0123456789</span><span class="y">0123456789</span><span class="g">0123456789</span><span class="b">0123456789</span><span class="i">0123456789</span><span class="v">0123456789</span><span class="r">0123456789</span>
</div>
```